# Full join is not giving me the desired result

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I'm trying to join the 2 tables below

**Table 1:**

```
| Name | city   | Country | Enabled |
|------|--------|---------|---------|
| Alex | London | UK      | 1       |
| Burt | Berlin | DE      | 0       |
| Carl | Moscow | RU      | 1       |
```

**Table 2:**

```
| Name  | post code | street |
|-------|-----------|--------|
| Burt  | 1234      | Road1  |
| Darek | 5678      | Road2  |
```

**for a desired result as**

```
| Name  | city_t1 | country_t1 | enabled_t1 | post_code | Street |
|-------|---------|------------|------------|-----------|--------|
| Alex  | London  | UK         | 1          | NULL      | NULL   |
| Burt  | Berlin  | DE         | 0          | 1234      | Road1  |
| Carl  | Moscow  | RU         | 1          | NULL      | NULL   |
| Darek | NULL    | NULL       | NULL       | 5678      | Road2  |
```

Can someone please help me with the sql code for this?

Comment: Show us the query that doesn't give you the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to know the answer:  `full join`:

```
select *
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     using (name);
```

This is standard SQL functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your SQL you are trying to execute.
As my friend here suggested, it should work.
In some environments you should use 'full outer join' syntax.

```
select *
from table1 t1 full outer join
     table2 t2
     using (name);
```

Comment: Which dbms has `OUTER` as mandatory keyword?